# "instagram graph api" (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (business_discovery) on node type (URL)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

When I try to operate business_discovery api on [Graph Api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) it return following error.
Please teach me how to get it work.

```
{"error": {
"message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (business_discovery) on node type (URL)",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 100,
"fbtrace_id": "A72pX1O2G5lr7lRTPV1aUCz" }}
```

the request i'm sending is from [business_discovery api page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/business_discovery) so i belive it correct.

my access token type are "Page" and it still valid.

```
(my user ID)?fields=business_discovery.username(bluebottle){followers_count,media_count}
```

I have following permission

- pages_show_listads_management
- business_management
- instagram_basic
- instagram_manage_comments
- instagram_manage_insights
- instagram_content_publish
- instagram_manage_messages
- pages_read_user_content
- pages_manage_engagement

Comment: _"on node type (URL)"_ - sounds like your `(my user ID)` there is not actually a user ID, but a URL ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Docs - IG User Business Discovery](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/business_discovery#reading), The endpoint is: `GET /{ig-user-id}?fields=business_discovery.username({username})`. Here, You need to use the **IG User Id** — an Instagram Business or Creator Account ID - that's connected to the Facebook Page. To get your **IG User ID**, you can follow the steps mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started).

The following request works for me:-

**Request:-**

```
GET /17841448XXXX?fields=business_discovery.username(bluebottle){followers_count,media_count,name}
```

**Response:-**

```json
{
  "business_discovery": {
    "followers_count": 442424,
    "media_count": 2074,
    "name": "Blue Bottle Coffee",
    "id": "17841401441775531"
  },
  "id": "17841448XXXXXXX"
}
```

Hope this helps.

[image]