# Instagram Graph API Error: Tried accessing nonexisting field (business_discovery) on node type (User)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Here is the error object I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (business_discovery) on node type (User)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "AV9wGf5yx2ZQln-HAnXcsoM"
  }
}
```

tried to hit this endpoint from the Graph Explorer:

me?fields=business_discovery.username(bluebottle){followers_count,media_count}

The error indicates that bluebottle is not a Business Account which does not make sense because it's also used as an example in the docs + when I try other business accounts I get the same Error.

Comment: _"The error indicates that bluebottle is not a Business Account"_ - no, it doesn't - it indicates that the account behind `me` is not a business or creator account.

Comment: Try following the instructions as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76380086/12326605